# JSP/Servlet Attribute Validation

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

Is there a way to validate request attributes passed from Servlet to JSP?

For example, in my Servlet I do something like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    request.setAttribute("foo", foo);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/bar.jsp);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

bar.jsp looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        ${foo.getBaz}
    </body>
</html>
```

In bar.jsp, is there a way to ensure that the "foo" attribute is a Foo object? We use the Maven JSPC plugin to compile JSPs and it'd be nice to catch refactoring/renaming errors (like Foo.getBaz() being renamed to Foo.getFluff()) at compile-time.

Comment: If you're using a MVC framework like JSF, Struts, Spring MVC, etc, then you could take benefit of existing framework-specific IDE plugins which may provide EL validation. E.g. JBoss Tools for JSF. However no one comes to mind for plain vainlla JSP/Servlet.

Answer (score 1):

check out the instanceof operator in java. It should solve your problem.

Comment: here is the link: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm

Comment: I'm not sure if you fully understand the question. How would you implement it in a way that it solves the OP's problem by normal JSP/JSTL/EL means?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scriptlet such as this:

```
<%
Foo foo = (Foo) request.getAttribute("foo");
String baz = foo.getBaz();
%>
```

and then use `baz` within your HTML as `<%= baz %>`